# Overriding official resolving URL for npm package

Tags: node.js, git, npm

My app uses `react-router-redux` which internally depends on `react-router`. Now, I have my own fork of `react-router` and wish to point my app to that instead. However, my app doesn't depends on `react-router` **directly** so I couldn't just modify my `package.json`.

One way to solve this is by modifying the `package.json` of `react-router-redux` but it means I need to fork `react-router-redux`. It becomes even more complicated if I have more libraries depend on `react-router`.

In this case, how to force my app to use my own repo of `react-router` (hosted in Github) instead of the official one? I could have my own tag for my version (e.g. `v1.0.1-myname`)